# Scripting Docker, Not Connected After Running Script?

Tags: bash, docker

So I have a script that looks like this:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    if [ $1 ]; then
        docker-machine start $1
        docker-machine env $1
        eval $(docker-machine env $1)
        docker ps -a
    fi
```

Once it has run though, the scope of these commands seem to be over. For instance I don't have a connection to the docker-machine once the script has run, but I'd like to script this part out so I can have access to it.

For instance, after running this script ("./script.sh") I still can't run "docker ps -a".

What's the reason this happens and how could I get it to effectively be connected to after executing this script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A script (or any other process) cannot modify the environment of its parent process.  That is precisely why `docker-machine env` emits shell code that needs to be evaluated with `eval`.

If you want these variables accessible outside of your script, you would need to arrange to run `eval $(docker-machine env <whatever>)` in your current shell.

Comment: Perfect! Between that and some reading I've gotten it figured out. Will do a short blog post with the finished solution. Thanks.